# PCLStorage not creating folder (or saving)

Tags: c#, xamarin, canvas, plugins, xamarin.forms

I have problem while using PCLStorage for Xamarin.Forms. I try to create new folder to save my canvas as image and it don't even want create that new folder. I don't know what is wrong because i already checked many guides how storage files on Xamarin and i didn't found any solution. My code so far is:

```
saveButt.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            String folderName ="testFolder" ;
            IFolder folder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
            folder = await folder.CreateFolderAsync(folderName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            ExistenceCheckResult folderexist = await folder.CheckExistsAsync(folderName);
            if (folderexist == ExistenceCheckResult.FolderExists)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Exists", "OK");

            }
        };
```

Comment: do you get an error or exception?  How do you know it's not working?  Which specific platform are you working on?

Comment: Code is in cross section of my app (or how i can name that Xamarin.Forms section), but i'm testing it on Android 7.0 API24. Program go through this normally, i click save and nothing appear, i can still draw on my canvas like i didn't clicked anything.And as i'm doing this displayAlert which should show up if that folder exists (i checked folders "by hand" too and there is no new folder). @Jason

Comment: your re-use of the "folder" variable is confusing.  I'd suggest using explicit variables for each instance of IFolder to clarify what your code is actually doing

Comment: @Jason true, when i created 
IFolder newFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
                ExistenceCheckResult folderexist = await newFolder.CheckExistsAsync(folderName);
It shows me that folder exists but i still can't find it (i displayed path where it should be but it isn't here).

Comment: Sooo, can anyone help ?